# backup of Xcode 4.3.3 installer

Tags: ios, installation, xcode4.3

To avoid any future support contingencies, I much prefer to backup a copy of a Xcode 4.3.3 (build 4E3002) **installer**.  Otherwise, future reported issues may be inconsistent within the test environment.  Instead of putting a machine in the closet with Xcode 4.3.3, or restore from disk image backup, I would prefer to be able to simply re-install 4.3.3.

With Xcode 4.2 you could download the installer.  With Xcode 4.3.3 I can only go to the App Store to download Xcode 4.3.3.  I wasn't able to find (or identify if it exists) the installer on my machine as a result of installing Xcode 4.3.3.

I'm really surprised to find that no one has raised this issue (that I've been able to find anyway).

I hope for one of three answers (with descending priority):

A) The path/name of the Xcode 4.3.3 installer (if it does stick around after install).
B) A link to download a Xcode 4.3.3 installer.
C) Tell me which files and paths are written, as well as install scripts, as a consequence of installing Xcode 4.3.3 using the App Store so I can bundle up the required files to manually install Xcode 4.3.3.

The worst case scenario is I force our users to update the application in when iOS updates are released.  But, I much prefer not to lock myself into this model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why worrying, you can always install newer versions on your machine and still have xcode 4.3.3 installed side by side

Comment: @Omar.  How so?  I'm not convinced that I can count on this as an option.  To upgrade to 4.3.3 I had to uninstall 4.2, upgrade to lion 10.7.4, and install 4.3.3.  Moreover, it's no secret that Apple doesn't push or support their previous versions.  You can't download anything but current builds...which is why I posted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the OLD way of downloading a separate installer was a kluge. With the advent of the App Store that was an interim solution that has now been replaced by the current behavior which is standard for All apps installed via App Store.

Theoretically each version of Xcode is better than the last :) mwahahaha.. No seriously lately they have been.

So... your users should just get the update.

Comment: Hello Cliff.  I appreciate your feedback.  Kludge or not: I stated this is the worst case scenario option.  I'd love to hear back from you if you can speak to any of the three answers of interest.

Comment: a)There is no path to the installer, it DOES NOT stick around & now behaves like any other iOS app that gets installed via the App Store. b) Don't think links are available for production releases, but sometimes if you google that you might find one laying around. But really, why bother? c) Can't help you there. Got better things to do than try to figure that out. Seriously dude, just use the App store. Apple worked pretty hard to make it work just like all the other Apps. They were pretty proud of that at the recent WWDC 2012 because they caught a lot of crap from devs for NOT doing that.

Comment: Point noted.  Thanks for your time.